# Limit Definition and properties related

Tags: limits

Let $\left \{ a_{n} \right \}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$ exists if and only if

(A)$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+2}$ exists

(B)$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+1}$ exists

(C)$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+1}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{3n}$ exist

(D)none of the above

They all seem correct to me. How to approach this ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should think about is the logic.  It is a basic theorem about sequences that if the limit of a sequence exists, then the limit of any subsequence exists (and is the same).  So if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists, then all the other limits mentioned exist and (A), (B), (C) are all true.  I suspect that this is what you are thinking.

**However**, the question didn't say "if", it said "if and only if".  So what you have to decide is, if (A) is true, does it follow that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists?  And the same for (B) and (C).

Here is a **hint**.  Can you devise a sequence $\{a_n\}$ for which $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+1}$ both exist but are not equal?  If you can then (B) is ruled out; if you can prove that this is impossible, then (B) is the answer.

And a **hint** for (C).  Start off thinking in the same way and consider the sequence $\{a_{6n}\}$.